Is rank of the length spectrum of a closed negatively curved surface/manifold infinite?
Suppose that $(S,\mathfrak{g})$ is a closed negatively curved Riemannian surface (or more generally a manifold). Negative curvature guarantees that the non-trivial conjugacy classes $\text{conj}(\pi_1(S))$ are in bijection with the closed geodesics on $(S,\mathfrak{g})$. The marked length spectrum
$$
\ell_\mathfrak{g} : \text{conj}(\pi_1(S)) \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}
$$
assigns to each conjugacy class the length of the corresponding closed geodesic in $(S,\mathfrak{g})$.
It is a well known fact (due to Dal'bo https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01235869) that the image of $\ell_\mathfrak{g}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is not contained in a discrete subgroup $c \mathbb{Z}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
My question is: can the image of $\ell_\mathfrak{g}$ be contained in a subgroup of the form
$$
c_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus c_2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus c_k \mathbb{Z} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i c_i \ \text{with} \ n_i \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
$$
for some $c_1,\ldots, c_k \in \mathbb{R}$? That is, can it be contained in a finite rank subgroup?
It seems like a very natural question to ask, but I've not been able to find any results about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

I’m pretty sure this is false for any hyperbolic surface, but let’s just consider $\mathbb{H}^2/PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.
For a matrix $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ with $tr(A)> 2$, the translation length of the assocated closed geodesic on $\mathbb{H}^2/PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is $2log(a)$, where $a$ is the positive eigenvalue of $A$, given by $a^2-a tr(A) +1=0$. This is a quadratic irrational over the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{tr(A)^2-4})$. Choose matrices $A_1, …, A_{k+1}$ so that the associated fields are independent (the eigenvalues generate  a field of degree $2^{k+1}$). Then the sum of the lengths are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Otherwise some product of powers of the eigenvalues of these matrices would be $1$, contradicting our choice of matrices.
The general case of hyperbolic surfaces should follow from the main result of this paper.
For negatively curved surfaces in general, I believe that the length spectrum may be contained in any dense subset $L\subset \mathbb{R}$, in fact by a small  perturbation of  the metric.
To describe a perturbation, enumerate the primitive closed geodesics $\{\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots\}$ (or rather their homotopy classes of loops whose geodesic representatives will change with the perturbation). Create a sequence of metrics $g_1,g_2, \ldots$ which converge to $g_\infty$, such that $l_{g_i}(\gamma_j) \in L, j=1,\ldots, i$. Given $g_i$, the closed geodesic $\gamma_{i+1}$ will not be contained in the union of the images of $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_i$.  Choose a small disk $D_{i+1}$ intersecting $\gamma_{i+1} - \cup_{j\leq i} \gamma_j$ and disjoint from $\cup_{j\leq i} \gamma_i$. Perturb the metric $g_i$ on $D_{i+1}$ so that the length of $g_{i+1} \in L$ and keeping the metric negatively curved. This perturbation does not affect the lengths of $\gamma_1,\ldots , \gamma_i$. Choosing small enough perturbations, we can guarantee that the metrics converge to $g_{∞}$ which has the desired property. Note however that $g_\infty$ won’t be analytic.

Thank you, this is really helpful!

@Zestglemonzi: I added an argument (not very well written) showing why the answer to your question is positive in general. I’m not sure if a real-analytic example can be found.

Thanks Ian, I agree that your argument works - this is the trick that I know to show that there isn't a finite set of conjugacy classes that determine the full length spectrum of a negatively curved structure (i.e. you perturb away from the union). The same goes for the conjugacy classes corresponding to the simple closed curves for a fixed metric - the union is not dense so they don't determine the full marked length spectrum.
